# Google play - how to identify the order number for a refund a user is asking for

Tags: android, google-play

I got a user request for an app refund. I understand that in the Payments Merchant Center you can select an order and initiate a refund. My problem is that I don't know wich purchase or order number is the right one. And the user doesn't have the order number (or should he?). So, how can I identify the purchase of a given buyer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order ID is sent to the user by Google in email receipt. You can then search order by ID and cancel it in Google Play console.